# python netaddr IP Network

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, network-programming

I have an IP address that I want to change and want the value to return as an IP network

so

```
addr = 192.168.0.0/24
ip = IPNetwork(addr) 
ip[2]
print ip
```

result

192.168.0.2/24 at the moment the result is 192.168.0.2 with out the network mask.

---

I have manage to do what I needed to do as follows

```
>>> addr = IPNetwork("10.0.0.0/24")
>>> addr
IPNetwork('10.0.0.0/24')
>>> mask = addr.prefixlen
>>> intip = IPNetwork(addr[-3])
>>> intip
IPNetwork('10.0.0.253/32')
>>>
>>> intip.prefixlen = mask
>>> intip
IPNetwork('10.0.0.253/24')
>>>
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I think you need to expand on your question. It is very unclear what you are asking. What are you trying to do? What should `ip[2]` do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get why you want to add the mask from the network to the (host-)ip, but I guess the most common way would be a format string:

```
>>> from netaddr import IPNetwork
>>> net = IPNetwork("192.168.0.0/24")
>>> print( "{0}/{1}".format(net[2], net.prefixlen) )
192.168.0.2/24
>>>
```

If for some reason you need the result as an IPNetwork object (with set host bits) you can also do it like so:

```
>>> net = IPNetwork("192.168.0.0/24")
>>> net.value += 2
>>> net
IPNetwork('192.168.0.2/24')
>>>
```